# How do I earn Hero Shards?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

It seems there is a currency in Injustice 2 for mobile called Hero Shards. I've been unable to work out how you earn this so far.

How can you?

Comment: I can tell someone else has been going hard on Injustice 2 IOS after it was released.

Comment: @Ramirez I downloaded it last night, and my phone has been on charge ever since...

Comment: Same here for me, totally am not Elite 2 already in the Arena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hero shards in Injustice 2 are used for upgrading the star level of your heroes and unlocking new heroes. To see how many you have you can click on any hero and see a bar underneath their star ranking with value of how many shards you own for them. Once you obtain enough shards you can upgrade your hero up to the next star level which makes them much more powerful. There are quite a few ways to obtain hero shards in Injustice 2 on IOS

- The first way is to buy Hero chests in the store which sell for 150 gems per chest and give you a hero instantly if you get something you do not have, or give you a handful of shards if you already have the hero.
- The second way is to buy the hero shards from the store. Every day there will be two heroes that have a few shards for sale in the store that sell for 100 gems for three.
- The third way is to buy them with Arena tokens. During every season in the arena they sell a selection of hero shards for different heroes that sell for 50 arena tokens and give you 5 shards per purchase and you can buy each character up to three times. You can refresh the store too to get more chances to buy shards.
- You can obtain shards by chance through operations you send your heroes on as well.
- There is a character Armored Superman that you can only obtain through achievements. When you complete various achievements you will receive a few hero shards specifically for Armored Superman.
- You can also obtain hero shards every weekend by taking part in the challenges going on. Do note you can only do challenges on the weekend.
- Lastly you can obtain hero shards randomly after some fights in the campaign as well.

Comment: You sure do know a lot about the game! Hopefully my votes weren't enough to trigger a reverse! (If that happens on here as well that is)

Comment: Yeah I've been playing since the game released so I've been at it for awhile. I hope it doesn't trigger a reversal but I think it would have to be a lot more for that to trigger.